# Xamarin: Binding: property not found on 'Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary', target property

Tags: c#, xamarin, logging, binding, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an application using a MVVM pattern. Bindings works good but when I'm debugging my application on an Android device (I have not this log on iOS part), I have the following log:

Binding: 'propertyName' property not found on 'Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary', target property: 'typeOfpropertyName'.

I don't necessarily implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my classes because it depends on my needs. For example, I have a ListView with DataTemplate (a CustomViewCell) and ItemSource (Binding a List with multiple MyObject inside):

**CustomViewCell:**

```
<ViewCell>
    <ViewCell.BindingContext>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ViewCell.BindingContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Image
            Source="{Binding PictureImageSource}"/>
        <Image
            Source="{Binding User, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

**MyObject.cs:**

```
public ImageSource PictureImageSource
{
    get
    {
        return ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(MyUrl));
    }
}

public User User
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

With that code I have the following logs:

Binding: 'PictureImageSource' property not found on 'Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Image.Source'

Binding: 'User' property not found on 'Xamarin.Forms.ResourceDictionary', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Image.Source'

I repeat everything works but I really want to remove those logs. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this line doing here:

```
<ViewCell.BindingContext>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ViewCell.BindingContext>
```

Ideally there should be a ViewModel containing `List<MyObject>`

`BindingContext` should be set for Page and `ItemSource` of `ListView` should bound to a `List<MyObject>` like this:

In ViewModel:

```
public List<MyObject> Objects {get; set;}
```

And then in xaml file for `ListView`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}"
```

And resource dictionary should be at element level, page level or application level. NOT in ViewCell's binding context. ViewCell shouldn't have a binding context as its just a template for ListView.

In your case:

```
<Grid.Resources>                
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! I thought the <ViewCell.BindingContext> was mandatory for ViewCells to declare converters but I was wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood it well, but if I did, you need just to change your resource dictionary to the Grid, for example.

See this example:

```
<ViewCell>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>                
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Image
            Source="{Binding PictureImageSource}"/>
        <Image
            Source="{Binding User, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Let me know if it works for you.